# Key sharing with RSA

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

I'm asking myself a question about the possibility of key sharing in RSA.
Is it possible to share a public or private key in the RSA-encryption algorithm without losing the security?

Comment: What is exactly aim of sharing for you?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of RSA is that you share the public key so anybody can send you a message.  You don't share the private key so nobody else can read the messages.